# Ruby on Rails - Radio inline buttons - Why is this option appearing as true/false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to understand why this is producing true or false.

Relevant code:

```
          <div class="form-group">
                <%= label(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'Can be Shipped?')%>
                <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="radio inline">
                    <%= radio_button(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, true, :checked => true)%>
                    <%= label(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'Yes', :value => true)%>
                </div>
                <div class="radio inline">
                    <%= radio_button(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, false)%>
                    <%= label(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'No', :value => false)%>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div
```

So, when I load up my form, and choose the option of Yes, to say the item can be shipped overseas, when I click the item itself on the store page, it has Shipped? as true. I know how to change it so when I choose Yes, when viewing the item it will appear as "Yes", using an if else statement on the home.html page.

I'm wondering why, when I change the :value in label to Yes, or No, it doesn't actually change from true to Yes. Can someone explain why this occurs?

[image: Ship]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Label is just for viewing purposes and for marking the error messages when a validation pertaining to the field it is associated with fails. If you need to change the `can_be_shipped` to come as 'Yes' or 'No', you will have to change the radio buttons as well.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'Can be Shipped?')%>
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="radio inline">
      <%= radio_button(:store_item, :can_be_shipped,'Yes', :checked => true)%>
      <%= label(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'Yes', :value => 'Yes')%>
    </div>
    <div class="radio inline">
      <%= radio_button(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'No')%>
      <%= label(:store_item, :can_be_shipped, 'No', :value => 'No')%>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```